# How to test moment.js with different locales in mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, locale, momentjs

I would like to test my locale-dependent date calculations with mocha. However, the locale does not seem to be reset in the different `describe` functions:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    moment = require('moment');

describe('English locale', function () {
    moment.locale('en');
    it('uses Sunday as start of week', function () {
        // Monday, 5th September 2016
        var d = moment('2016-09-05').weekday(0);
        expect(d.date()).to.equal(4);
    });
});

describe('German locale', function () {
    moment.locale('de');
    it('uses Monday as start of week', function () {
        // Monday, 5th September 2016
        var d = moment('2016-09-05').weekday(0);
        expect(d.date()).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```

How can I create a a specific "locale" environment inside my `describe` blocks?

The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) shows only how to format objects in a locale-specific way, I want to *create* moment objects in a specific locale.

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround is to localize the individual dates. This can be done in two ways:

1) by creating them differently (only works when creating from string)

```
describe('German locale', function () {
    it('uses Monday as start of week', function () {
        // Monday, 5th September 2016
        var d = moment('2016-09-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'de').weekday(0);
        expect(d.date()).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```

2) By explicitly localizing the generated date:

```
describe('German locale', function () {
    it('uses Monday as start of week', function () {
        // Monday, 5th September 2016
        var d = moment('2016-09-05').locale('de').weekday(0);
        expect(d.date()).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```

You could even define a helper function and replace all date-constructing calls to `moment` with that function:

```
function germanMoment() {
    return moment.apply(moment, arguments).locale('de');
}

describe('German locale', function () {
    it('uses Monday as start of week', function () {
        // Monday, 5th September 2016
        var d = germanMoment('2016-09-05').weekday(0);
        expect(d.date()).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```